# Can't mount a samba share

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, cifs

I think I did everything I need, I installed `cifs-utils` on the server and the client, plus `smbclient` on the client.

I also share the folder like this:

[image: screenshot of configuration to share the folder]

```
[Ventas]
comment = varpeta de ventas
path = /mnt/ventas
public = yes
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
```

I restarted the Samba service.

On the client I used the line:

```bash
mount -t cifs //172.16.0.10/mnt/ventas /mnt/importar -o user=externo,password=asd
```

That IP is the IP from the server. I'm sharing `/mnt/ventas` and I want to mount it on `/mnt/importar`.

But I'm getting this error:

[image: screenshot of terminal showing error messsage]

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Also the user `externo` is in my server and client, and I gave a name to the workgroup on the client and  the server.

I'm going crazy, does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Could be most anything, see https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting and http://vlkan.com/blog/post/2015/01/08/smb-mount-troubleshoot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mount a samba share using the internal path of the server. You use the network path to the share. In this case it's //172.16.0.10/ventas because ventas is the share name.

Try this instead:

```
mount -t cifs //172.16.0.10/ventas /mnt/importar -o user=externo,password=asd
```